# What is the definition of a "German Employer" for a German Blue Card?

Tags: germany, blue-card

I currently hold a German Blue Card (since 2019 but not yet eligible for permanent residency, so I already don't need approval to change jobs) and would like to change to a new employer registered legally in Lithuania but would like to remain in Germany. They have a Betriebsnummer issued by Bundesagentur für Arbeit but they are not registered as a legal entity in Germany (i.e. they have no Handelsregisternummer). I've been told that I would be paying taxes in Germany like all other German employees.

I would like to know:

1. What is the legal definition of a "German employer" wrt. the Blue Card? Is a Betriebsnummer registration enough or must they be a legal entity in Germany (i.e. they need a Handelsregisternummer)?
2. In my case, given all other requirements are met, is it legal for me to work for them?

Comment: Update: I called the Bundesagentur für Arbeit and the person on the call seems to agree that as long as there is a Betriebsnummer and they are paying German social contributions it should be OK, but advised me to get a response in writing from the Auslanderbehörde (which is mission impossible but I'll try) in case it's needed.

Comment: Which documents do you have right now?  (as far as determining whether it's legal for you to work for them).